# Android Linux kernel power-off sequence

Tags: linux, sequence, power-off

I'm working with Linux kernel of Android and I have a problem. I'm trying to make a flow chart of my Android phone's kernel power-off code sequence.

If I press the power button on my phone and choose "Power off" to turn off my device. I wonder what's going on inside the system. Which kernel module will be the initial module of power-off sequence? Which kernel modules call which system calls during the whole power-off process?

I got the log file of my device as below..

```
...
ghost[362]: [Ghost] Now, 50th boot.
[  119.307156] msm_hsl_power: Unknown PM state 1
[  129.966017] pil-q6v5-mss fc880000.qcom,mss: PBL returned unexpected status -284491765
[  129.972866] pil-q6v5-mss fc880000.qcom,mss: mba: Failed to bring out of reset
[  129.992102] modem_notifier_cb: sysmon_send_event error -19
[  129.996628] M-Notify: General: 5
[  129.999825] msm_ipc_load_default_node: Failed to load modem
[  131.336799] pil-q6v5-mss fc880000.qcom,mss: PBL returned unexpected status -284491765
[  131.343844] pil-q6v5-mss fc880000.qcom,mss: mba: Failed to bring out of reset
[  131.351708] modem_notifier_cb: sysmon_send_event error -19
[  131.356216] M-Notify: General: 5
[  131.359430] smd_pkt_open failed on smd_pkt_dev id:0 - subsystem_get failed for modem
[  132.385289] param_sec_operation FAIL LLSEEK
[  132.388448] sec_open_param PARAM OPEN FAIL
[  132.392715] set_dload_mode <0> ( c01882a0 )
[  132.397069] (sec_debug_set_upload_magic) 0
[  132.496318] Power down.
[  132.497733] Powering off the SoC
[  132.500972] set_dload_mode <0> ( c0188348 )
[  132.505717] Calling SCM to disable SPMI PMIC
```

I wonder if restart.c in "arch\arm\mach-msm" is the first module which initial the power-off sequence after I press the "Power off" soft button?

I'm a newbie in Linux. I will be very grateful for your help!

Comment: What is the kernel version you are using? What are the manufactuirng details of the phone?

Comment: I'm using kernel version 3.4.0-g63e50df-dirty, init by systemd, chipset by Qualcomm.

Comment: How did you obtain this kernel version? Do a `uname -r`.

Comment: I used command "uname -r" in the kernel command line

Comment: @iqstatic: It's safe to say this is an Android phone, you won't get the usual `uname -r` output from desktops/servers you expect. ;)

Comment: android is linux-like system not linux. you should not assume something and post a question like this. Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming this is an Android phone?

There is a difference between the shutdown sequence for Linux and for Android, even though Android is based on the Linux kernel. What the Linux shutdown sequence does is to start by setting the runlevel to 0; this will cause any services to shut down, before allowing for a clean halt and poweroff.

But Android doesn't have runlevels, because they're not a feature of the Linux kernel, but of initd.

Hopefully this will give you something to start with for the Linux shutdown sequence. You should start by learning about runlevels.

Details of the kernel shutdown sequence are [in this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122557/how-does-the-system-shutdown-of-a-linux-kernel-work-internally).

Comment: I have googled about this but I didn't find anything closely related to my problem. I'm trying to make a code sequence in detail during the whole power-off process. I've read the topic that you mentioned, it's very helpful. I will be very grateful if you give me a more detailed explaination closely to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you press power button on a linux system, a shell script is invoked which is generally present at `/etc/acpi/actions/power.sh`. This script internally looks for ID of the first active X11 session. Then it checks if there is a power manager, otherwise it calls the shutdown command. I suggest you look into the source code for [shutdown](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/drivers/base/power/shutdown.c?v=2.6.11.8) command and see for yourself what all functions/syscalls it invokes internally. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to understand the code flow of the power-off sequence of my Android phone. I've seen the directories structure of Android and I found it similar to Linux. I cannot find the module shutdown.c in any directory. Could you give another suggestion? Thank you very much!

Comment: As suggested by chiastic-security in his answer, Android and Linux are different, even though Android is based on the Linux kernel.

Comment: I could see the sequence mentioned in iqstatic's answer. The OP's question said Linux. +1 for silly down vote.

Comment: @Ben Thanks for your advice. I've corrected my question.